# How to access specific object in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

an API is returning a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "1-3",
            "short_name" : "1-3",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Acacia",
            "short_name" : "Acacia",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Alamos 2da Sección",
            "short_name" : "Alamos 2da Secc",
            "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Santiago de Querétaro",
            "short_name" : "Santiago de Querétaro",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Querétaro",
            "short_name" : "Qro.",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Mexico",
            "short_name" : "MX",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "76160",
            "short_name" : "76160",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I wold like to access the "sublocality" object and read it's value which  in this case is "alamos 2da secc". I know the JSON must first be parsed using JSON.parse but im not sure how to access a specific object. Is a for loop necessary? or is there a way i can match the type field for every object to be "sublocality"

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @Louis If my answer below solved your problem, would you please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the grey checkmark √?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If there may be multiple addresses that are sublocalities**, I would go with this approach:

```
const response = JSON.parse(apiResponse)
const addressesWithSublocality = response['result']['address_components'].filter(address=>{
    return address['types'].includes('sublocality')
})
console.log(addressesWithSublocality.map(address=>address['short_name']))
```

The `.filter` function takes an array and trims it down to just the items that return "true" -- in this case, the addresses whose `types` includes `"sublocality"`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

The `.map` function returns a new array that is the result of running a provided function on each item in the original array -- in this case, returning the `short_name` of each address.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

**If there will only ever be one address that is a sublocality**, I would go with this approach:

```
const response = JSON.parse(apiResponse)
const addressWithSublocality = response['result']['address_components'].find(address=>{
    return address['types'].includes('sublocality')
})
console.log(address['short_name'])
```

`.find` is similar to `.filter` in that it trims down an array based on which items return "true", but `.find` returns just one item, whereas `.filter` always returns an array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

*Note: Instead of using bracket notation you could just use dot notation, e.g. instead of `response['result']['address_components']` you could write `response.result.address_components`. I just prefer the former syntax when accessing JSON.*

Answer (score 0):

Use Array [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the required Object.

```js
var data = `{"html_attributions":[],"result":{"address_components":[{"long_name":"1-3","short_name":"1-3","types":["street_number"]},{"long_name":"Acacia","short_name":"Acacia","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Alamos 2da Sección","short_name":"Alamos 2da Secc","types":["sublocality_level_1","sublocality","political"]},{"long_name":"Santiago de Querétaro","short_name":"Santiago de Querétaro","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Querétaro","short_name":"Qro.","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Mexico","short_name":"MX","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"76160","short_name":"76160","types":["postal_code"]}]},"status":"OK"}`

data = JSON.parse(data)

var res = data['result']['address_components'].find((e) => {return e.types.indexOf('sublocality') !== -1})

console.log(res['short_name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Array#filter find all the names that match the type passed as a parameter.

There may be more than one possible match.

```js
const data ={"html_attributions":[],"result":{"address_components":[{"long_name":"1-3","short_name":"1-3","types":["street_number"]},{"long_name":"Acacia","short_name":"Acacia","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Alamos 2da Sección","short_name":"Alamos 2da Secc","types":["sublocality_level_1","sublocality","political"]},{"long_name":"Santiago de Querétaro","short_name":"Santiago de Querétaro","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Querétaro","short_name":"Qro.","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Mexico","short_name":"MX","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"76160","short_name":"76160","types":["postal_code"]}]},"status":"OK"};

function findMatches(type){
  return data.result.address_components
  .filter(({types})=>types.includes(type))
  .map(({short_name})=>short_name)
  .join(", ");
}

const res = findMatches("sublocality");

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [_find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#find) from Lodash to find the object

```js
const response = {
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "1-3",
            "short_name" : "1-3",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Acacia",
            "short_name" : "Acacia",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Alamos 2da Sección",
            "short_name" : "Alamos 2da Secc",
            "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Santiago de Querétaro",
            "short_name" : "Santiago de Querétaro",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Querétaro",
            "short_name" : "Qro.",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Mexico",
            "short_name" : "MX",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "76160",
            "short_name" : "76160",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}

const addressWithSub = _.find(response.result.address_components , (e) => {return e.types.includes('sublocality')})

console.log(addressWithSub.long_name)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.js"></script>
```